# Feed validator in hybris?

Tags: spring-security, sap-commerce-cloud

I have used `MultipartFile` in my controller but it is not taking the file value. Could you please help me?

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public String uploadFileHandler(
  final Model model, 
  @ModelAttribute final FileUploadModel fileUploadModel, 
  final BindingResult bindingResult, 
  final ImportCSVSavedCartForm importCSVSavedCartForm
) {
  final String file = fileUploadModel.getCsvFile();
  if (!file.isEmpty()) {
    uploadExcelFile(file);
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid nobody will be able to help you with so little information.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your bean into the following part of the **spring-filter-config.xml** as a new entry in your storefront extension.

```
<alias name="defaultFileUploadUrlFilterMappings" alias="fileUploadUrlFilterMappings" />
<util:map id="defaultFileUploadUrlFilterMappings" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter">
    <entry key="/import/csv/*" value-ref="importCSVMultipartFilter"/>
</util:map>
```

**importCSVMultipartFilter** bean will give you a clue on how to do that.

Comment: The bean which you ask me to define is already there in my storefront.Kindly suggest

Comment: I don't know what is your controller request mapping value but just for your method you are supposed to use "/uploadFile/** as a key. I assume you already added these beans as MultipartFilter and CommonsMultipartResolver like importCSVMultipartFilter and importCSVMultipartResolver

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your reply.I have added like below,even though i am getting null value from csv file.kindly suggest.<alias name="defaultFileUploadUrlFilterMappings" alias="fileUploadUrlFilterMappings" />
 <util:map id="defaultFileUploadUrlFilterMappings" key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter">
  <entry key="/uploadFile/*" value-ref="fileUploadMultipartFilter"/>
 </util:map>